# Swift CoreData Blank Rows Without Defined Relationship

Tags: swift, core-data, swift5

I have blank rows in the on device sqlite table but the null data has been stripped out from the API request, it has no relationship between the Searches and Albums table.

My core data controller defines the context and save method.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataController {

    private init() {}

    static let shared = CoreDataController()

    var mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext {

        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "PerfectTune")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (_, error ) in

            if let error = error as NSError? {

                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving Support
    func saveContext() -> Bool {

        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {

                try context.save()
                return true
            } catch {

                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }

        }

        return false
    }
}
```

The Model

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataModel {

    weak var delegate: DataReloadTableViewDelegate?
    let coreDataController: CoreDataController
    var items: [Albums] = []

    init(_ coreDataController: CoreDataController) {
        self.coreDataController = coreDataController
        self.coreDataController.mainContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    }

    internal func saveSearchAlbums(responseData: Root) throws {

        let newSearch = Searches(context: coreDataController.mainContext)

        newSearch.searchQuery = responseData.attr.forField

        for (_, element) in responseData.albumMatches.album.enumerated() {

            let newAlbum = Albums(context: coreDataController.mainContext)

            let artistName = element.artist
            let albumName = element.name
            let imageUrlTwo = element.image[2].text
            let imageUrlZero = element.image[0].text
            let imageUrlOne = element.image[1].text

            var imageUrl: String = ""

            if !JustLetters.blank(text: imageUrlZero) {
                imageUrl = imageUrlZero
            }

            if !JustLetters.blank(text: imageUrlOne) {
                imageUrl = imageUrlOne
            }

            if !JustLetters.blank(text: imageUrlTwo) {
                imageUrl = imageUrlTwo
            }

            if !JustLetters.blank(text: artistName) && !JustLetters.blank(text: albumName) && !JustLetters.blank(text: imageUrl) {

                newAlbum.searches = newSearch
                newAlbum.artist = artistName
                newAlbum.name = albumName
                newAlbum.imageUrl = imageUrl

                newSearch.addToAlbums(newAlbum)
            }
        }
        // Save context
        _ = coreDataController.saveContext()
        fetchAlbumsByKeyword(searchTerm: responseData.attr.forField)
    }

    internal func fetchAlbumsByKeyword(searchTerm: String) {

        // Create Fetch Request
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Albums")

        // Add Sort Descriptor
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        // Add Predicate
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchTerm)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        do {
            items = try  coreDataController.mainContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Albums]
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        delegate!.reloadAlbumsTable()
    }

    internal func fetchAllAlbums() {

        // Create the FetchRequest for all searches
        let allAlbums: NSFetchRequest = Albums.fetchRequest()

        do {
            items = try coreDataController.mainContext.fetch(allAlbums)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The relationship with Searches is not defined.

[image]

The CoreData Model

Constraints are set to maintain a unique recordset.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this condition:

```
if !JustLetters.blank(text: artistName) && !JustLetters.blank(text: albumName) && !JustLetters.blank(text: imageUrl) { ...
```

is failing.  My guess is that your API request is returning rows where **some** of the fields are null.  Try compounding the expressions with OR rather than AND:

```
if !JustLetters.blank(text: artistName) || !JustLetters.blank(text: albumName) || !JustLetters.blank(text: imageUrl) { ...
```

Comment: applying that check before the core data object creation loop so CD only creates clean objects, thanks